# Android Watch/Phone MessageApi

Tags: wear-os

I am working on an app for Android Watch that requires the mobile app to be on or in background. I tried using the MessageApi in order to communicate with the app on the phone, but even if the app is not on, i get a message back like it is on.

What would you suggest to check whether the phone app is running (doesnt matter whether it is foreground/background) before i enable the activity on the Android Watch?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have registered a WearableListenerService in your mobile app, that will be invoked by the framework even if your app is not running (and will be invoked if your app is running, too). If, however, you are not using that service, then to receive messages or notification on changes in the wear network in your mobile app, you would need to register one or more callback listeners for the type of messages/data that you are interested in. In that case, that means if your app is not running, you will not be getting those callbacks on your mobile app. To use this, however, be sure to manage the lifecycle of your listeners in your mobile app according to your needs. For example, one can register for such listeners in onResume() of an activity and unregister in onPause(). The consequence of that is if your activity loses focus (but still alive), that activity will not receive the callback (even though as an instance it is still running). You may want to define an Application instance for your app and use that to listen for callbacks but, again, it depends on the exact nature of your needs and app.

Answer (score 0):

You can search for nodes and parse them for needed result, or to check if you have a nearBy node

```
private Collection<String> getNodes() {
    HashSet <String>results = new HashSet<String>();
    NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes =
            Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mGoogleApiClient).await();
    for (Node node : nodes.getNodes()) {
        results.add(node.getId());
    }
    return results;
}
```